# Как отсортировать полученный JSON файл?

Tags: python, json, api

Ребят, простите за вопрос, я новичок совсем. Не нашел ответа у гугла, поэтому пишу тут.
Задача стояла в том, чтобы получить данные с этой таблицы яндекс расписания https://voronezhvokzal.ru/raspisanie-poezdov/

Для этого я использовал API яндекса. Вот мой код:

```py
import requests
    
    
url = ("https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/schedule/?apikey=TOKEN&station=s2014001&transport_types=train&direction=arrival&date=2021-01-13")
res = requests.get(url)
print(res.text)
```

Проблема заключается в том, что он мне выдал огромный объем данных в формате Json. В запросе я указал все, что мне нужно, но все равно выводятся просто все данные, отсортировать в самом запросе не вышло. Мне нужны данные только с этой таблицы в нынешний момент, но он выдал данные за все будущие даты - минуя мою сортировку. Делал все по документации яндекса. Вот [ссылка на документ](https://yandex.ru/dev/rasp/doc/reference/schedule-on-station.html#format)

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить только мою таблицу из этого файла?**
**Простите за много текса, я не знаю, можно ли такое постить..**

**Вот, что мне выдал запрос:**

```json
{
  "pagination": {
    "total": 16,
    "limit": 100,
    "offset": 0
  },
  "schedule": [
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-12T23:22:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "382S_6_2",
        "title": "Грозный — Москва",
        "number": "382С",
        "short_title": "Грозный — Москва",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "11, 13, 15, 17, 19 января, 29 марта, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 29 апреля, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 мая, …",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T00:28:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-13T00:20:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "123N_14_2",
        "title": "Новосибирск — Белгород",
        "number": "123Н",
        "short_title": "Новосибирск — Белгород",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31 января, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18 февраля, …",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T02:00:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-13T03:12:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "471M_1_2",
        "title": "Москва — Адлер",
        "number": "471М",
        "short_title": "Москва — Адлер",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "ежедневно по 13.01, кроме 05.01, 06.01, 08.01",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T03:48:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-13T06:48:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "034S_1_2",
        "title": "Москва — Владикавказ",
        "number": "034С",
        "short_title": "Москва — Владикавказ",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "ежедневно по 15.01",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T07:23:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": null,
      "thread": {
        "uid": "737ZH_4_2",
        "title": "Воронеж — Москва",
        "number": "737Ж",
        "short_title": "Воронеж — Москва",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "ежедневно",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T07:33:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-13T07:12:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "146YE_4_2",
        "title": "Москва — Назрань",
        "number": "146Э",
        "short_title": "Москва — Назрань",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31 января, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21 февраля, …",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T07:55:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-13T11:25:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "374M_3_2",
        "title": "Смоленск — Симферополь",
        "number": "374М",
        "short_title": "Смоленск — Симферополь",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 63438,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "Гранд Сервис Экспресс (Таврия)"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "13, 17 января, 1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 19, 21, 25, 27 мая, 1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 19, 21 июня, …",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T12:15:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-13T12:14:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "035A_0_2",
        "title": "Санкт-Петербург — Адлер",
        "number": "035А",
        "short_title": "Санкт-Петербург — Адлер",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 января, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 февраля, …",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T12:55:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-13T14:18:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "036S_4_2",
        "title": "Адлер — Санкт-Петербург",
        "number": "036С",
        "short_title": "Адлер — Санкт-Петербург",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "только 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 января, 12, 13 февраля",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T14:57:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-13T15:08:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "109S_4_2",
        "title": "Анапа — Москва",
        "number": "109С",
        "short_title": "Анапа — Москва",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "чт, сб по 13.01, а ещё 05.01, 11.01, 13.01",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T15:57:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": null,
      "thread": {
        "uid": "739ZH_1_2",
        "title": "Воронеж — Москва",
        "number": "739Ж",
        "short_title": "Воронеж — Москва",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "ежедневно",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T16:21:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-13T19:02:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "306S_4_2",
        "title": "Сухум — Москва",
        "number": "306С",
        "short_title": "Сухум — Москва",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "13, 17 января, 28, 29, 30 апреля, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 мая, …",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T19:37:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": null,
      "thread": {
        "uid": "025V_2_2",
        "title": "Воронеж — Москва",
        "number": "025В",
        "short_title": "Воронеж — Москва",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 24, 28, 31 января, 4, 7, 11, 14, 18, 21, 25, 28 февраля, 4 марта, …",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T20:30:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-13T20:06:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "033S_12_2",
        "title": "Владикавказ — Москва",
        "number": "033С",
        "short_title": "Владикавказ — Москва",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "ежедневно по 15.01",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T20:55:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-13T20:46:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "145S_7_2",
        "title": "Назрань — Москва",
        "number": "145С",
        "short_title": "Назрань — Москва",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31 января, 2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21 февраля, …",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-13T21:28:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    },
    {
      "except_days": null,
      "arrival": "2021-01-14T01:24:00+03:00",
      "thread": {
        "uid": "382YA_10_2",
        "title": "Москва — Грозный",
        "number": "382Я",
        "short_title": "Москва — Грозный",
        "carrier": {
          "code": 112,
          "codes": {
            "icao": null,
            "sirena": null,
            "iata": null
          },
          "title": "РЖД/ФПК"
        },
        "transport_type": "train",
        "vehicle": null,
        "transport_subtype": {
          "color": null,
          "code": null,
          "title": null
        },
        "express_type": null
      },
      "is_fuzzy": false,
      "days": "14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30 января, 1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22 февраля, …",
      "stops": "",
      "departure": "2021-01-14T02:09:00+03:00",
      "terminal": null,
      "platform": ""
    }
  ],
  "station": {
    "code": "s2014001",
    "title": "Воронеж-1",
    "station_type": "station",
    "popular_title": "",
    "short_title": "",
    "transport_type": "train",
    "station_type_name": "станция",
    "type": "station"
  },
  "date": "2021-01-13",
  "interval_schedule": [],
  "event": "departure"
}
```

Comment: тут все поезда, проходящие  2021-01-13 через станцию s2014001... в чем ошибка?

Comment: Я не понимаю как вывести мне только номер поезда, направление и время. Мне нужны только эти данные, как в таблице.

Comment: как со словарями: for train in data['schedule']:    print(f'title {train["title"]}') и т.д...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите вывести только номер поезда, направление и время, то вам нужно сделать так:

```py
import json
import requests

link = "Здесь вставьте вашу ссылку"
r = requests.get(link)
trains = json.loads(r.text)

for train in trains["schedule"]:
    print(f"Отправка в {train['arrival']}")
    print(f"Номер поезда: {train['thread']['number']}")
    print(f"Направление: {train['thread']['title']}\n")
```

Comment: in trains['schedule']:

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, не заметил, когда писал :D

Comment: спасибо вам большое!